# Start a Windows Run command in Python (Browser protocol)

Tags: python, windows

I want to open a specific application on my computer which can be done by running

```
application://open/window/
```

in Windows from the Windows Run-command (Start -> Run, resp. Windows-key + R).

How can I run this from Python?

The following does **not** work:

```
import os
os.system("application://open/window/")
```

since this will run the command from the Windows command-line, which does not know what `application:` is.

Comment: try `os.system("start application-name")` or you can use `os.system("cd path-to-app-folder")` and then `os.system("start application-name")`

Comment: Nice! That worked.. Didn't know it was so easy. Thank you!

Comment: Ps1.: it seems that you can't change the directory using `os.system("cd path")`.
Ps2.: if my answer solved your problem, consider accepting it as an correct answer. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start a program using:

```
os.system("start application-name")
```